# Hide folder from github code, but see it when github actions is triggered

Tags: git, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a folder named `cert`, which I don't want to be visible inside the repository's code, But I need to see it when github workflow runs.

```
cert
    ca-cert.pem
    ca-key.pem
    server-cert.pem
    server-key.pem
    server-req.pem
```

I first put the folder inside .gitignore. I then put each and every file inside the folder as a github secret, which works, but is very repetitive and I figured there must be a better more efficient solution.

Are there any better options to do that?

Comment: GitHub secrets are for such use case. You can automate this with GitHub CLI i.e. [`gh secret`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret) command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put them in Github at all if you can manage. If you do store them in GitHub, [consider using the gh cli in a script to automate the storage of these secrets](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_secret). Optionally store them at the GitHub Organization level instead of the Repo level to be able to assign access to them from the UI.

```
$ gh secret set MYSECRET < myfile.txt
```

> Note: [Be careful adding multi-line and structured data in a secret. GitHub Actions will have a much harder time ensuring the secret isn't printed in the logs in this case](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#using-secrets). Reformatting, minifying, or decoding the secret will transform it in such a way that GitHub actions won't recognize teh value anymore and therfore won't scrub it from the logs.

### But

Tools like Azure Key Vault and Hashi Corp Vault are safer places to store your keys. [And even then, I'd worry if you put your CA-cert private key in there, those should be locked away safely, preferably on a HSM or on offline storage.](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168050/how-to-store-openssl-ca-private-key-securely#:%7E:text=Here%20are%20three%20scenarios%20with%20increasing%20security%3A%201,the%20CA.%20...%204%20Use%20an%20HSM.%20) A GitHub workflow has no business with a Certificate Authority private key.

If your workflow needs access to these keys it can then request them from the vault.